# set(single object in array) returns set(string)

Tags: python

See part 1:
http://artificial-intelligence-class.org/homeworks/hw4/homework4.html

I am trying to return a set(array) for one of the answers in my homework but I am simply getting back a set(string), and so it says my answer is incorrect. This only occurs when the array I am casting has a length of 1. This is annoying because later I will do set difference between two arrays and it will not compile because the two aren't the same type. Here is my code:

```
    def get_values(self, cell):
        if cell in self.board:
            value = [self.board[cell]]
            return set([tuple(value)])
        else:
            values = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
            return set([values])
```

Executing

```
b = read_board("sudoku/hw7-medium1.txt")
print(Sudoku(b).get_values((0, 1)))
```

returns
`{'1'}`
when it should return
returns
`{[1]}`

Comment: `{[1]}` is not possible, a set cannot contain a list.

Comment: What about dictionary? Set cant have list inside it

Comment: What will be returned when there are more than 1 values inside set?

Comment: @PrakashDahal if there are more than 1, a list works

Comment: http://artificial-intelligence-class.org/homeworks/hw4/homework4.html see part 1

Answer (score 1):

set() is a constructor for the set object.

It receives an iterable as the argument.  [Iterable](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/set) is a sequence (string, tuple, etc.) or collection (set, dictionary, etc.) or an iterator object to be converted into a set.

This means, if you pass an array, a tuple, etc as a single parameter to set, it simply creates a set of the elements it contains.

Further, it is not possible for a set to contain a list as an element

```
a = (1,2,[3,4])
```

Will give you an error saying that list is not a hashable object.

It is, however, possible to accomplish what you are trying to do with:

```
   a = set(
          ((1,2,3),)  # this is a tuple, whose 1st element is a tuple
          )
```

a now contains

```
{(1, 2, 3)}
```

Still, no actual lists:

```
>>> a = set( ([1,2,3],) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The reason lists are a problem is that they are dynamic.  You can change an element of a list - but tuple is constant.  You don't want to build a hash whose keys can change without you knowing it.